# Throwing tomatoes at a poster of a politician

Tags: canada, politics, protest

As a form of protest, imagine:

1. Printing a poster of a politician's face
2. Placing it on a wall (with permission of the wall's owner) in a generally public space
3. Handing out tomatoes to be thrown at the poster.

What legal troubles can arise?

EDIT:
The jurisdiction is Canada, particularly Ontario.
My apologies for not thinking of this detail.

Comment: Any particular jurisdiction?

Comment: In North Korea this may mean the death penalty, in Texas this is a typical Friday night... Need to know where you are talking about...

Comment: Were you planning on cleaning up afterward? And using organic or non-organic or GMO-free produce?

Comment: given the stated jurisdiction, this is not too broad in my view.

Comment: Of course I would clean up!

Comment: ...asking for a friend? ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you contain and clean up the mess and don’t create a public nuisance, you’re good to go.

Comment: So, there aren't any defamation laws that would come into play?

Comment: @Andrey what false statement of facts that damages their reputation has been made?

Comment: None! Just trying to be careful here. Hoping not to get nailed with some lawsuit that would blind-sight me. Thank you for the answers.